# Firefox clip-path + box-shadow bug

Tags: css, svg, firefox, clip-path

I'm using `clip-path` property to make elements of irregular shapes like this:

```css
#triangle {
   background-color: indigo;
   clip-path: url(#shape);
   height: 200px;
   width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="shape">
         <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 1 1"></polygon>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>  
</svg>
```

But it just so happened that one of the elements with such shape on the page had a `box-shadow` applied to it as well:

```css
#triangle {
   background-color: indigo;
   clip-path: url(#shape);
   height: 200px;
   width: 400px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="shape">
         <polygon points="0 0, 1 0, 1 1"></polygon>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>  
</svg>
```

The shadow is obviously invisible, because `clip-path` clips it. When I use this in MS Edge or Chrome everything is fine, there is a triangle with sharp angles and no visible shadow as it's supposed to be. On firefox the first snippet works the same way, just fine. But the second snippet renders a trapezoid instead of a triangle on firefox, like on the image. It disappears as soon as `box-shadow` property is disabled. And `box-shadow` isn't even of `indigo` color like the triangle, it's transparent black

[image: Second snippet on firefox]

Is this a firefox bug, is there a way to avoid it? Of course I can remove `box-shadow` since it's clipped anyway, but it's still interesting to see what causes this.

Comment: looks like a new bug to me, drop-shadow is failing too.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, I also think so, I've found that `clip-path` acts as if `box-shadow` was a part of this `div`. I'm going to file it to firefox bug tracker

Comment: `clip-path:polygon( 0 0 , 100% 0 , 100% 100%, 0 0);` instead the svg has the same issue with drop-shadow, box-shadow is not drawn at all (as before) ;)

Comment: For a workaround you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552950/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-box-shadow-that-follows-the-shape-of-a-clip-path-po

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's indeed a bug in firefox. [Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1684757) is the bugzilla issue

Comment: Is it? What specification says so? I accept Chrome and Firefox have different renderings. Can you explain why Chrome is correct?

Comment: @RobertLongson, well, it's a known fact that `clip-path` doesn't work with `box-shadow`, because the latter is being clipped, there are articles on that on the internet. The [specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#typedef-geometry-box) says that "if no reference box is specified, the `border-box` will be used as reference box." and `border-box` doesn't include `box-shadow`, so it is a bug