# Is it possible for an element to have a custom shape and box-shadow at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div in a shape of a trapezium with a shadow in the back. Testing two strategies:

```css
.trapezium-a {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #333;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 13px rgb(0 0 0 / 90%);
}

.trapezium-b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 13px rgb(0 0 0 / 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezium-a"></div>
<br>
<div class="trapezium-b"></div>
```

Both of those do not work with box-shadow property - either shadow is a box or not visible at all.

Is there a way to achieve this effect on non rectangle element?

Comment: As already mentioned you could use filter: drop-shadow;and also you can make pseudo shadow using another element. Here is the link to Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koaxcbfv/           And in case you need them in detail:
 https://css-tricks.com/breaking-css-box-shadow-vs-drop-shadow/
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40553237/15387341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter: drop-shadow` which will apply a drop-shadow on the ***image item*** as `box-shadow` will add shadow around the ***elements frame***.

```css
.trapezium-a {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #333;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 6px 13px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezium-a"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter: drop-shadow()` instead of `box-shadow`:

```css
.trapezium-a {
  filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 255, .2));
}
```

`filter: drop-shadow()` follows the shape better than `box-shadow`.